# unable to get list of printers with powershell

Tags: powershell

I have deployed a shared printer with "printui /ga" to work on computers.
now when I try to get a list of printers from these computers, I am unable to see shared printers. I used get-wmiobject and get-printer methods still no luck.

If I can't find a solution to this, I am at the point, I will start looking for ways to install a shared printer with PowerShell methods.

Comment: SO has rules: [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you did this and got nothing back?

```
Get-Command -Name '*printer*' |  Format-Table -AutoSize
# Results
<#
CommandType Name                 Version Source                      
----------- ----                 ------- ------                      
Function    Add-Printer          1.1     PrintManagement             
Function    Add-PrinterDriver    1.1     PrintManagement             
Function    Add-PrinterPort      1.1     PrintManagement             
Function    Get-Printer          1.1     PrintManagement             
Function    Get-PrinterDriver    1.1     PrintManagement             
Function    Get-PrinterPort      1.1     PrintManagement             
Function    Get-PrinterProperty  1.1     PrintManagement             
Function    Read-PrinterNfcTag   1.1     PrintManagement             
Function    Remove-Printer       1.1     PrintManagement             
Function    Remove-PrinterDriver 1.1     PrintManagement             
Function    Remove-PrinterPort   1.1     PrintManagement             
Function    Rename-Printer       1.1     PrintManagement             
Function    Set-Printer          1.1     PrintManagement             
Function    Set-PrinterProperty  1.1     PrintManagement             
Function    Write-PrinterNfcTag  1.1     PrintManagement             
Cmdlet      Out-Printer          3.1.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility
#>

Get-Printer |  Format-Table -AutoSize
# Results
<#
Name                          ComputerName Type  DriverName                        PortName                                                                                                      
----                          ------------ ----  ----------                        --------                                                                                                      
...                                                                                                         
Microsoft XPS Document Writer              Local Microsoft XPS Document Writer v4  PORTPROMPT:                                                                                                   
Microsoft Print to PDF                     Local Microsoft Print To PDF            PORTPROMPT:                                                                                                   
Fax                                        Local Microsoft Shared Fax Driver       SHRFAX:                                                                                                       
...                                                                   
#>


# Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function
(Get-Command -Name Get-Printer).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Get-Printer).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Get-Printer -Examples
# Results
<#
Get-Printer –Name "Microsoft XPS Document Writer"

Get-Printer –Name "Microsoft XPS Document Writer" | Format-List

Get-Printer -ComputerName PrintServer
$Printer = Get-Printer -Name “Microsoft XPS Document Writer"
Rename-Printer -InputObject $printer "MXDW"
#>
Get-help -Name Get-Printer -Full
Get-help -Name Get-Printer -Online
```

***Update***

Continuing from my comment.

You'd still use the same cmdlet, but in a remote call to the printer target

```
Get-Printer -ComputerName '\\RemoteHostName'

# Or

$ComputerList | 
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $PSItem -ScriptBlock {Get-Printer}
```

Since you used printui to do this, why not just use printui to get the list/info from the remote host?

```
printui.exe /?

# Results
<#
Examples:
...
   Enumerate per machine printer connections: 
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /ge /c\\machine
...
   Get printer settings: 
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /Xg /n "printer"
   Get printer settings saving results in a file: 
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /f "results.txt" /Xg /n "printer"
...
#>
```

Comment: I have tried the method you described above. I can get stand alone printers list with powershell commands. As long as the printer is installed with a driver. I have a shared printer that is installed with printui /ga /n\\printerserver\sharename. I am unable to see this shared network printer with powershell commands.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As for this...
['I have a shared printer that is installed with printui /ga /n\\printerserver\sharename.']
... you did not provide that clarity in your orinial post.

As for this... 
['I will start looking for ways to install a shared printer with PowerShell methods.'] 
.. that would not change your situation

You'd still use the same cmdlet, but in a remote call to the printer target